# AddEventListener for Multiple Button

Tags: javascript

i have multiple user comments wrapped in `<article>` with the same content structure and the same class. the main part that i need to playaround with js is to get text and attribute value from each user comment when the reply button clicked then add those thing to form input value.

this is the html structure

```
<div class="comments">

  <article id="comment-1" class="comment parent">
    <span class='comment-author'>John Doe</span>
    <p class="body">Lorem ipsum  af farm-to-table brunch XOXO portland small batch edison bulb yr hella 3 wolf moon</p>
    <a id="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6" class="reply-btn"  title="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6">reply</a>
  </article>

  <!-- this one is reply for the first comment -->
  <article id="comment-1r1" class="comment reply">
    <span class='comment-author'>Jane</span>
    <p class="body">Lorem ipsum  af farm-to-table brunch XOXO portland small batch edison bulb yr hella 3 wolf moon</p>
    <a id="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fdjkl4m5" class="reply-btn"  title="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6">reply</a>
  </article>

  <article id="comment-2" class="comment reply">
    <span class='comment-author'>Foo</span>
    <p class="body">Lorem ipsum  af farm-to-table brunch XOXO portland small batch edison bulb yr hella 3 wolf moon</p>
    <a id="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fdj409d4" class="reply-btn"  title="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6">reply</a>
  </article>


</div>

<!-- the form -->
<form>
  <input class="replyThread" type="hidden" name="fields[replyThread]" value="">
                <input class="replyID" type="hidden" name="fields[replyID]" value="">
                <input class="replyName" type="hidden" name="fields[replyName]" value="">

</form
```

as you can see each user comment have a unique user name also unique attribute value on the `reply-btn` but they generaly they have same class.

this is my workaround

```
    const replyButton = document.querySelector('.reply-btn');
    const replyThread = document.querySelector('.replyThread');
    const replyID = document.querySelector('.replyID');
    const replyName = document.querySelector('.replyName');
    const threadValue = document.querySelector('.reply-btn').getAttribute("title");
    const idValue = document.querySelector('.reply-btn').getAttribute("id");
    const nameValue = document.querySelector('.comment-author');

    replyButton.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
        replyThread.innerHTML = threadValue;
        replyID.innerHTML = idValue;
        replyName.setAttribute('value', nameValue.innerHTML );
    })
```

the only problem is the button seems to work only for the first comment, when i click the other nothing happen. i try using querySelectorAll but unfortunately it can work with addEventListener

my question is how to make the reply button working and get the text and attribute value from the right place (each user comment)?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a Nodelist which is a collection and not an individual entity. So you have to loop through the collection and attach the event for each button

Comment: I think after first button clicked, you are loading another replay-btn. right ?

Comment: i thought so, unfortunately  i have no idea how to do that

Comment: @DineshPatra no, there is no interaction in reply button, i just need each button get the user name and attrbute value from the button to input

Comment: Okay in that case as @KrishnaPrashatt alrwady told, you need to loop. querySelector  returns first matched. You need to use document.querySelectorAll. QuerySelectorAll returns array of references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use event delegation on the `.comments` container: watch for clicks, and if the clicked target matches `.reply-btn`, get its `.title` and ID, and get the thread title by accessing the `.comment-author` in its container, and then you can put those into the form:

```js
const [replyThread, replyId, replyName] = document.querySelectorAll('form > *');

document.querySelector('.comments').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.reply-btn')) {
    return;
  }
  replyId.value = target.id;
  replyThread.value = target.title;
  replyName.value = target.parentElement.querySelector('.comment-author').textContent;
});
```

```html
<div class="comments">

  <article id="comment-1" class="comment parent">
    <span class='comment-author'>John Doe</span>
    <p class="body">Lorem ipsum af farm-to-table brunch XOXO portland small batch edison bulb yr hella 3 wolf moon</p>
    <a id="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6" class="reply-btn" title="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6">reply</a>
  </article>

  <!-- this one is reply for the first comment -->
  <article id="comment-1r1" class="comment reply">
    <span class='comment-author'>Jane</span>
    <p class="body">Lorem ipsum af farm-to-table brunch XOXO portland small batch edison bulb yr hella 3 wolf moon</p>
    <a id="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fdjkl4m5" class="reply-btn" title="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6">reply</a>
  </article>

  <article id="comment-2" class="comment reply">
    <span class='comment-author'>Foo</span>
    <p class="body">Lorem ipsum af farm-to-table brunch XOXO portland small batch edison bulb yr hella 3 wolf moon</p>
    <a id="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fdj409d4" class="reply-btn" title="de255ea0-ddde-11e9-84d7-5d6e5fd4ffd6">reply</a>
  </article>


</div>

<!-- the form -->
<form>
  Form
  <input class="replyThread" name="fields[replyThread]" value="">
  <input class="replyID" name="fields[replyID]" value="">
  <input class="replyName" name="fields[replyName]" value="">

</form>
```

While `querySelectorAll` is possible too, it'd require adding a separate listener to each button, which is overkill. (event delegation also allows for functionality for dynamically added elements too).